# NSTableView using autolayout creates width constraint on cell view

Tags: macos, autolayout, nstableview, appkit

I'm using a view-based NSTableView with Auto Layout turned on. Auto Layout provides the cell views with two horizontal constraints: a Cell_MinX that is tied to its NSTableRowView's leading edge, and a Cell_Width constraint that is adjusted based on the width of the table.

[image]

However, when the window's width is resized > 1000 points, the Cell_Width constraint stops increasing at 1000 and the width constraint locks at 1000 points until the window's width is smaller than this limit. This seems to be an arbitrary value inserted by the table view, and I can't figure out how to ensure that value is *always* the width of the table. I built the table view in IB which doesn't permit creating constraints on the table's cell view. I created a [sample project](https://github.com/seanmrich/AutolayoutTest) to demonstrate the problem. Here's Xcode's view debugger with the window's width sized greater than 1000.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not arbitrary. Interface builder sets the maximum Table Column size to 1000. If you remove all the columns, set it to zero, then add a single column, and make sure it sets it to View based table view, then it will set it to the maximum allowed size (a very big number). Or you can just set the maximum size yourself in interface builder.

[image: Table Column Maximum Size]

Comment: Thanks @TimTwoToes! I feel sheepish for such a silly oversight, but I appreciate you setting me straight.

Comment: No problem @smr. A lot of nooks and crannies in AppKit. Reading the documentation it says, that it will set new columns maximum width to CGFloat.max, but apparently Interface Builder disagree and the default column width is set to 1000. Took me by surprise as well. That is the purpose of this forum. Do not hold back :)

Comment: If you want a single column that tracks the width of the table, it seems you have to set the width to the exact width of the table in interface builder here, otherwise the column will not track the table size (I tried setting column width to a large size, as well as the max).